# Escaping single and double quotes for mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

I am using mysql.connector python library with python 2.7

I have a unicode string which may or may not contain single and double quotes.
Here are the things I tried for my escape function:

```
def escape(string):
#string.MySQL.escape_string()
#string = string.decode('string_escape')
#string = string.encode('unicode-escape').replace("'", "''")
#string = string.encode('unicode-escape').replace('"', '\"')
#string = string.encode('unicode-escape').replace("'", u"\u2019")
#string = string.encode('unicode-escape').replace('''"''', u"\u201D")
#string = string.encode('unicode-escape').replace('''''', u"\u201D")
return string
```

Nothing seems to have worked. I tried using [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cext-escape-string.html) function but still gives mysql syntax error.

I need something within mysql.connector library which escapes the single and double quotes without breaking the unicode as well as mysql query.

Here is an example of SQL query I am using:

```
"""SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msg_id = '{msg_id}'""".format(**db_dict)
```

Let me know if any more details needed

**EDIT**: Example SQL query updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQLdb officially declares to use the [`format`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) paramstyle, but it also supports the [`pyformat`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes) style*, so if you want to use parameters from a dict, you can use:

```
db_dict = {'msg_id': "1'2'3", ...}
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msg_id = %(msg_id)s", db_dict)
```

Using string manipulation to create sql queries only leads to sql injection vulnerabilities, so you should never do it.

---

*... most db connectors that use python string formatting behind the screen do the same, they specify one of format or pyformat as paramstyle but actually support both. The dbapi2 doesnt't allow to specify two values here, but it doesn't forbid to support multiple parmstyles either. If you write code that potentially uses an unknowon dbapi2 connector it's enough that you can query a supported paramstyle, being able to know all would be nice but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

`cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msg_id = %s', (db_dict['msg_id'],))` is what you want to run here. Standard string escapes aren't supported by python's database interface, and, per @bobince's comment, are a security hole to boot.

Comment: `"""SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msg_id = '{msg_id}'""".format(**db_dict)` is what i tried where `db_dict` is a dictionary which contains `msg_id` key

Comment: Never use `.format` to put values into an SQL query. This is a SQL injection security hole. Instead use parameterised queries, by passing in the data in a separate second argument to `execute()`, as in @hd1's example.

Comment: Instead of escaping queries, I escaped each and every string before passing to the query.

Also, as per the suggestions, I have stopped using `format` for query processing.

Comment: But you were not escaping strings and shouldn't use `format` for queries, which was my whole point in answering your question!